# How to find a specific object in a STL container

Tags: c++, containers, std

I want to find a specific object in a std::list where the object's attribute meets an input argument.

I found a solution using a unary predicate with find(.) or find_if(.) but in I need a binary function.

Why can't I just let the iterator be the reference of the object (like java) and check the field via the reference? Is there a way to do that without using find/find_if...

Comment: Which compiler are you using? If it's a recent GCC or VC version, it will have lambda functions (of the next version of the C++ standard) implemented, which make this so much easier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I found a solution using a unary predicate with find(.) or find_if(.) but in I need a binary function.

No – you *do* need a unary predicate – after all, the `find_if` function only compares with *one* object (the current object in the list). Your predicate needs to know which attribute value to compare with:

```
struct compare_with {
    int attr_value;
    compare_with(int attr_value) : attr_value(attr_value) { }

    bool operator ()(your_object const& obj) const { return obj.attr == attr_value; }
};
```

Now you can invoke `find_if`:

```
result = find_if(your_list.begin(), your_list.end(), compare_with(some_value));
```

> Why can't I just let the iterator be the reference of the object (like java) and check the field via the reference?

You can. But it’s absolutely not clear what you mean by this. Just iterate over the list.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that:

```
list<myclass>::iterator i;
for(i = mylist.begin(); i != mylist.end(); ++i)
{
    if(i->field == value_to_check_for)
        break;
}

// now i is an iterator pointing to the object if it was found
// or mylist.end() if it wasn't
```

But of course, I can't see why you'd need a binary predicate if you're just checking one object at a time.